# Wrong exception is thrown

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that acts as a progress form, and I execute tasks as follows:

```
protected override void OnShown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //Run task here...
        });
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException oex)
    { }
    catch
    { 
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

And the calling method is:

```
try
{
    using (var progress = new ProgressForm(() =>
    {
        //The task to run async...
    }))
    {
        progress.ShowDialog();
    };
}
catch (MyCustomException cex)
{ }
catch (Exception ex)
{ }
```

A `MyCustomException` is thrown by the task, so the progress form just rethrows it. However, back in the calling method, this exception isn't caught (caught in the `catch (Exception ex)` block) because the exception it gets from the progress form is somehow `TargetInvocationException`, and its `InnerException` is of type `MyCustomException`.

Why does this happen and is there a way to make sure that `MyCustomException` thrown from the progress form reaches the calling method as is?

Comment: `Exception` is the base class of all exceptions which means it *will* catch any `MyCustomException` exception. Your code though doesn't show any attempt to throw, which method calls which one. It shows code *hiding* exceptions. In any case, progress forms don't need a background thread. `ShowDialog()` will block the UI thread, which is probably *not* what you want. Use `Show()` instead

Comment: Where is the first code snippet located? I guess someting like an `async void` handler for the form's `Load` event? So there is noone awaiting the task this method created. Your code is expecting `ShowDialog` to throw the exception, but that's not what's happening, because `ShowDialog` does not await your load handler.

Comment: I'd suggest to perform exception handling completely inside the progress form and use it's `DialogResult` and an extra exception property to propagate the task's result/failure to the caller.

Comment: It is same as in TPL where an unhandled exception that is thrown by user code that is running inside a task would result in AggregateException that wraps custom exception. Reflection throws `TargetInvocationException` when runtime call to some method fails. You could catch your exception inside of the function where exception is thrown.

Comment: Your edit cannot be your real code, the compiler would raise error CS4033. You cannot use `await` in a method that's not declared `async`.

Comment: Also, you have two places in your sample code where the task is run. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
try
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //Run task here...
    });
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
    foreach (Exception inner in ex.InnerExceptions)
    {
         if (inner is MyCustomException)
         {
             //todo smt..
             throw inner;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? OP told that the task throws the `MyCustomException`. Your code awaits to the task. Where does the `AggregateException` come from? [Here](https://ideone.com/A0GHia) is a sample that shows that there is no `AggregateException` to catch. (I somehow miss the progress form.)

Comment: Read: [exception-handling-task-parallel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library)

Comment: I read the link you provided. But there is no `await` at all that unwraps the exceptions. Your code uses await and I think that's the point for catching an `AggregateException` vs. `MyCustomException`. See [5 Things you should know about async/await in C#](https://binary-studio.com/2014/06/04/5-things-you-should-know-about-asyncawait-in-c/) point 2.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can implement your ProgressForm in a way that it is shown `async` and await to it.
A sample implementation could look like that one:

```
public class ProgressForm : Form
{
    private ProgressForm()
    {
    }

    public static async Task ShowAsync(Form owner, Action<IProgress<(string Message, int Progress)>> action)
    {
        owner.Enabled = false;
        try
        {
            using (var frm = new ProgressForm { StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent })
            {
                frm.Show(owner);

                try
                {
                    var progress = new Progress<(string Message, int Progress)>(frm.OnProgress);
                    await Task.Run(() => action(progress));
                }
                finally
                {
                    frm.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            owner.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnProgress((string Message, int Progress) args)
    {
        // Report progress to this ProgressForm here.
        // This line is only for demonstration. Please add controls to the form.
        this.Text = $@"{args.Message} {args.Progress}%";
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind that this will call `Show` instead of `ShowDialog`. The owner is disabled so that it behaves like a modal form (only for that parent!).

The usage of may look like:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    void DoSomeWork(IProgress<(string Message, int Progress)> progress = null)
    {
        var loops = 5;
        for (var i = 0; i < loops; ++i)
        {
            progress?.Report(($"Loop {i + 1}", (i + 1) * 100 / loops));
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

        throw new DivideByZeroException("...");
    }

    try
    {
        await ProgressForm.ShowAsync(this, DoSomeWork);
    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Yeah...");
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

This code performs a `Thread.Sleep` in a `Task.Run`! This is only a demonstration and I need a sample that consumes time.